Can a ordinary differential equation with non unique solution have a smooth solution?
If we have an equation that satisfies the Peano existence theorem, can the solution to the equation be smooth? (As in continuous for all derivatives?)

Can it be?  Of course.  Do you mean to ask if it must be smooth?

Sure. Take $\begin{cases}y'=F(y,t)\ y(0)=c\end{cases}$ with $F$ continuous and solution set ${u_i}{i\in I}$, and single out a solution $u_0$. Then, $\begin{cases}y'=F(y+u_0(t),t)-u_0'(t)\ y(0)=0\end{cases}$ has solution set ${u_i-u_0}{i\in I}$, among which is the $0$ solution.

Don't know if any ODE could, but at least a Delayed Differential Equation $$f'(t)=2f(2t+1)-2f(2t-1)$$ has a smooth bump function as solution: look here for details
